# Posts sortable column not sorting properly for custom field numbers

Tags: php, posts, custom-field, sort, pre-get-posts

I have a custom field for view counts that are stored as numbers. I added a Views column, and made it sortable, but they are not sorting properly.

The results when I click on the Views column are something like this:

```
Views
=====
1900
10992
10004
280
18
4015
...
```

Here is my code:

```
/**
 * Add view counts to admin columns
 */
add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns', 'eri_posts_column_views' );
function eri_posts_column_views( $columns ) {
    $columns['post_views'] = 'Views';
    return $columns;
}
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'eri_posts_custom_column_views' );
function eri_posts_custom_column_views( $column ) {
    if ( $column === 'post_views') {
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        $meta_key = 'eri_post_view_count';
        $count = 0;
        if (get_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, true ) && get_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, true ) != '') {
            $count = get_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, true );
        }
        echo $count;
    }
}


/**
 * Make admin columns sortable
 */
add_filter('manage_edit-post_sortable_columns', 'eri_view_count_sortable_column');
function eri_view_count_sortable_column($columns){
    $columns['post_views'] = 'post_views';
    return $columns;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'eri_view_count_custom_orderby' );
function eri_view_count_custom_orderby( $query ) {
    if( ! is_admin() )
        return;

    $orderby = $query->get( 'orderby');

    if( 'post_views' == $orderby ) {
      $query->set('meta_key','eri_post_view_count');
      $query->set('orderby','meta_value_num');
    }
}
```

I've tried changing `meta_value_num` to `meta_value`... not working.

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue using the code you provided. Everything works for me.

The only problem: when you order by View Count then all posts having no `eri_post_view_count` key disappears from the list until you order posts by something different.

Comment: Hmm.. I wonder why it's not working for me. I printed the $query and it shows what I set in the array, but I'm wondering if something else is overriding it. Also, all posts have the meta key; when a new post is created it starts with 0. I appreciate the response, though.

Comment: @MaxYudin, I just tried my code on a different site and it works fine. Something is messing with it on the site I need it on. :( Any suggestions on where to look?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after adding the same code to a different site I run. It was working fine on that site with the same theme and mostly the same plugins. I narrowed it down to another function I made (thankfully it wasn't another plugin). The other function was sorting something on the front end, so all I had to do was add `if (!is_admin())` to that function. So the moral of the story is, I screwed up in a completely different area. :(

Answer (score -1):

Can you please set query as per below code?

```
$query->set('orderby','meta_value meta_value_num');
```

or below:

```
$query->set('orderby','meta_value');
```

Comment: I mentioned in my post that I already tried that and it didn't work. Thanks, though.